# Accessing a PDF stored in iBooks (on a jailbroken device)

Tags: ios, jailbreak, books

On a jailbroken iPad, I was looking for a way to access a particular PDF from iBooks. The files reside in `/var/mobile/Media/Books`, so basically I was looking for a way to find the random filename of a particular book. Is there any method?

Comment: This site works better if the question doesn't already contain the answer. I've removed it from your edit, can you please add it again as a answer on its own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various files (`.plist`s residing in `/var/mobile/Media/Books`), but the only one that seemed up to date also regarding renamed titles was

```
/var/mobile/Applications/iBooks/Documents/BKLibrary_database/iBooks_v*.sqlite
```

This file can be opened with iFile's SQLite Editor and under the Key `ZBKBOOKINFO` there's the mapping between filenames and book/pdf titles.

Comment: exactly. I had this in my combined question and answer after finding out that I wasn't allowed to answer my own question immediately. Then I was too lazy to separate it later  ヽ（´ー｀）┌